# Running django and flask on same apache server

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi

I am trying to run to run django and flask on the same apache server.

```
WSGISocketPrefix /var/www/wsgi
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin name@email.com
        ServerName  domain.com
        ServerAlias www.domain.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/
        LogLevel warn
        WSGIDaemonProcess apache processes=2 maximum-requests=500 threads=1
        WSGIProcessGroup apache
        Alias /media /var/www/media/

        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/djangoapps/django.wsgi
        WSGIScriptAlias /app1 /var/www/flaskapps/app.wsgi
</VirtualHost>
```

1. The first `WSGIScriptAlias` runs a django app in the root: domain.com.
2. The second instance of `WSGIScriptAlias` needs to run a flask app in a subdomain: `app1`.

But since the main site sits over django, when I try to hit: `domain.com/app1`, django's `urls.py` tries to handle that url command. But urls.py should not handle it, since its an independent flask app.

Any ideas how can I go about it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure if this would solve the problem, but have you tried changing the order of your script alias so that `/app1` is found before `/` ?

```
WSGISocketPrefix /var/www/wsgi
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin name@email.com
        ServerName  domain.com
        ServerAlias www.domain.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/
        LogLevel warn
        WSGIDaemonProcess apache processes=2 maximum-requests=500 threads=1
        WSGIProcessGroup apache
        Alias /media /var/www/media/
        WSGIScriptAlias /app1 /var/www/flaskapps/app.wsgi
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/djangoapps/django.wsgi

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who want to achieve the same in 2018 this really helped me:

https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/deploy/apache/deploy/python/

I know it is off topic, but I found this question like 20 searches before I found the link to the Description from Passenger....

How ev's here is an excert from the tutorial:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.phusion.nl
    DocumentRoot /websites/phusion/public
<Directory /websites/phusion>
    Allow from all
    Options -MultiViews
    # Uncomment this if you're on Apache >= 2.4:
    #Require all granted
</Directory>

Alias /subapp /websites/secondapp/public
<Location /subapp>
    PassengerBaseURI /subapp
    PassengerAppRoot /websites/secondapp

    PassengerAppType wsgi
    PassengerStartupFile passenger_wsgi.py
</Location>
<Directory /websites/secondapp/public>
    Allow from all
    Options -MultiViews
    # Uncomment this if you're on Apache >= 2.4:
    #Require all granted
</Directory>
```