# running different servers (django and java) for different urls at same host

Tags: java, django, apache, tomcat, wsgi

I'm trying to figure out how I might go about running two different servers at the same site.

In particular, I want to use Django/Apache for most of my URLs, but for one URL I'd prefer to use Java (for performance and to leverage a particular third-party library).

For example,

```
www.website.com/user/80     is-handled-by    Django
www.website.com/groups      is-handled-by    Django
www.website.com/getResult   is-handled-by    Java
```

will be handled by Django, but

would be handled by a Java backend.

Now I'm quite willing to accept alternative solutions - for example, **perhaps it's best to just run the Java code using Python's subprocess module**.

If this is possible, how would I go about configuring it, and which Java server will work best?

Comment: You can setup virtual hosts with nginx to achieve this

Comment: Just realised http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357296/running-django-and-flask-on-same-apache-server?rq=1 is probably a good place to start...

Comment: yup.. exactly what i was refering to

Comment: hang on a second though - it's not quite the same as Java doesn't ususally go through wsgi... does it?

Comment: Actually, I think I'm going to install Django into Jython instead - that way I can use the third-party library but still benefit from Django's awesome ORM